# XSLT last position within attribute

Tags: xslt, string-formatting

I need to check whether a node with certain attribute is the last in the loop, and accordingly insert and ampersand before the last node. I tried using the

```
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
```

doesn't seem to take into consideration the attribute value.

Here's the XML

```
<creators and-others="no">
            <creator type="personal">Roche, R.L.</creator> 
            <creator type="personal">Moulin, D.</creator> 
            <creator type="personal">James, K.</creator> 
            <creator type="affiliation">CEA Centre d'Etudes Nucleaires de Saclay, 91 - Gif-sur-  zYvette (France). Dept. d'Etudes Mecaniques et Thermiques</creator> 
</creators>
```

I need the output as, `Roche, R.L., Moulin, D., & James, K.`

Also, is there a way, to get the count of values for the "creator" node, with attribute "personal" ?

Comment: +1. You need to use the proper _axis_ according to the template context. See my (complete) answer.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, shortest (among the currently posted answers), simple and easy solution that doesn't use any conditional XSLT instructions at all. :)

Comment: Also added brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not counting the followng siblings inside the matching template? The last count `creator[@type='personal']` node following sibling will be zero.

**XSLT 2.0** tested under **Saxon-HE 9.2.1.1J** (also wroking as **XSLT 1.0** on **MSXSL 4.0**)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    >

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/creators">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="creator"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="creator[@type='personal']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(following-sibling::creator[@type='personal'])=0">
                <xsl:text>&amp; </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="creator"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on your input, produces:

```
Roche, R.L., Moulin, D., & James, K.
```

---

According to the template context, you can always use axis to get the count of the nodes. Example:

```
<xsl:template match="/creators">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(child::creator[@type='personal'])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

will set `$count` to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating over `<xsl:for-each select="creator[@type='personal']">` and use your `<xsl:if>` there. The XPath should select all those elements, for which attribute `type` has the value of `personal`.

You can use a similar expression in the `count` function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  <xsl:if test="count(//creator[@type='personal']) &gt; 0">
    Found personal
  </xsl:if>
```

If you want to store it in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="PersonalCount" select="count(//creator[@type='personal'])"></xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a predicate `[@type='personal']` to select only the desired `<creator>` elements. Then your test condition works without using any counts or referring to sibling elements. You should also test if there is only one `<creator type="personal">`, otherwise you'll end up outputting an extra `&` or a comma. Therefore `<xsl:choose>` is here handier than `<xsl:if>` alone.

Sample code below. You could also use `<xsl:for-each select="creator[@type='personal']">` instead of having a separate template for `creator` and calling `<xsl:apply-templates select="creator[@type='personal']"/>` if you want to do this inside an existing template.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="creators">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="creator[@type='personal']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="creator">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given input

```
<creators and-others="no">
            <creator type="personal">Roche, R.L.</creator>
            <creator type="personal">Moulin, D.</creator>
            <creator type="personal">James, K.</creator>
            <creator type="affiliation">CEA Centre d'Etudes Nucleaires de Saclay, 91 - Gif-sur-  zYvette (France). Dept. d'Etudes Mecaniques et Thermiques</creator>
</creators>
```

it produces the following output

```
Roche, R.L., Moulin, D. & James, K.
```

Comment: A comma is missing after `D.`.

Comment: @empo: Oh, look at that. Missing comma was intentional. I'm so used to that in lists there should not be a comma before "and" or "&" that I didn't notice that this extra comma was originally required in the question. If this comma is needed, just change `<xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text>` with `<xsl:text>, &amp; </xsl:text>`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a shorter solution that doesn't use any XSLT conditional instructions at all:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="creator[@type='personal']"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "creator[@type='personal'][position()>1 and not(position()=last())]">
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="creator[@type='personal'][position()=last()]">
  <xsl:text>, &amp; </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<creators and-others="no">
    <creator type="personal">Roche, R.L.</creator>
    <creator type="personal">Moulin, D.</creator>
    <creator type="personal">James, K.</creator>
    <creator type="affiliation">CEA Centre d'Etudes Nucleaires de Saclay, 91 - Gif-sur-  zYvette (France). Dept. d'Etudes Mecaniques et Thermiques</creator>
</creators>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Roche, R.L., Moulin, D., & James, K.
```

> Also, is there a way, to get the count
>   of values for the "creator" node, with
>   attribute "personal" ?

**Use**:

```
count(/*/creator[@type='personal'])
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of pattern matching instead of XSLT conditional instructions.
2. Making use of the XSLT (default) processing model and built-in templates.